# load_script がnot declaredになる。

Tags: c, lua

cppにLuaを組み込んで下記、エラーで困っています。
教本「スクリプト言語によるゲーム開発」を参照しながら、下記コードを記述したのですが、
下記エラーが出て、困っています。

アドバイスの程、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int GetSelection(const char *title){

    char input[100];

    printf("%s >",title);

    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    printf("\n");

    if(strlen(input)==0 || !isdigit(input[0])){
        return -1;
    }
        return atoi(input);
}

struct SItemInfo{
    char name[100];
    int  price;
};

typedef struct SItemInfo ItemInfo;

#define MAX_SHOP_ITEMS 5

ItemInfo shop_items[MAX_SHOP_ITEMS] = {
    {"薬草",100},
    {"こん棒",1000},
    {"布の服",2000},
    {"",-1},
    {"",-1},
};

const char* GetItemName( int index){
    if(( index < 0 ) || (index>= MAX_SHOP_ITEMS)){
        return NULL;
    }
        return shop_items[index].name;
};

const int GetItemPrice( int index){
    if(( index < 0 ) || (index>= MAX_SHOP_ITEMS)){
        return -1;
}
        return shop_items[index].price;
};


void PrintStackItem(lua_State *L, int idx){
    int type = lua_type(L,idx);
    switch(type){
    case LUA_TSTRING:
    //
    printf("index %2d : type=%s : %s \n",idx,                               lua_typename(L,type),lua_tostring(L,idx));
    break;
    case LUA_TNUMBER:
//
 printf("index %2d : type=%s : %f\n",idx,           lua_typename(L,type),lua_tonumber(L,idx));
     break;
    case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
//          
    printf("index %2d : type=%s : %s \n",idx,     lua_typename(L,type),lua_toboolean(L,idx) ? "true" :"false");
    break;
    defalut:
    printf("index %2d : type=%s \n",idx, lua_typename(L,type));
    break;
    }
 }          

 void PrintStack(lua_State *L){

    printf("----- stack -------\n");
    int top = lua_gettop(L);
    //
    for(int i=top; i>=1; i--){
        PrintStackItem(L,i);
    }
    printf("----- ----- -------\n");
    //
    for(int i=-1; i>=-top; i--){
        PrintStackItem(L,i);
    }
    printf("----- ----- -------\n");

 }

     int GetItemNameGlue(lua_State *L){
  //    printf("GetItemName() 関数実行\n");
     //スタックを表示
     //PrintStack(L);
     //
    int index = (int)lua_tonumber(L,1);
    //
    const char *name =GetItemName(index);
    //
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    //
    lua_pushstring(L, name);
    //
    //PrintStack(L);

    return 1;

 }

 int GetItemPriceGlue(lua_State *L){
 // printf("GetItemName() 関数実行\n");
    //スタックを表示
 // PrintStack(L);
     //
     int index = (int)lua_tonumber(L,1);
     //
     int price =GetItemPrice(index);
     //
     lua_settop(L, 0);
    //
    lua_pushnumber(L, price);
     //
 // PrintStack(L);

     return 1;
 }

 int s_money = 0;

 int GetSelectionGlue(lua_State *L){
     //
     const char *title = lua_tostring(L,1);
     //
     int index = GetSelection(title);
     //
     lua_settop(L, 0);
    //
    lua_pushnumber(L, index);

    return 1;
 }


 int GetMoney(){
      return s_money;
 }


 void SetMoney(int money){
     s_money = money;
 }

 int GetMoneyGlue(lua_State *L){
     //
    int money = GetMoney();
     //
     lua_settop(L,0);
     //
    lua_pushnumber(L,money);
    return 1;
 }

 int SetMoneyGlue(lua_State *L){
     //
     int index = (int)lua_tonumber(L,1);
     //
     SetMoney(index);
     //
     lua_settop(L,0);
     return 0;
 }




 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
     //乱数初期化
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
     for(int i=0; i<100; i++) rand();

    //LuaのVMを生成する。
    lua_State *L = lua_open();

     //LUaの標準ライブラリを開く
    luaL_openlibs(L);

     //
    lua_pushnumber(L, MAX_SHOP_ITEMS);
    lua_setglobal(L, "MAX_SHOP_ITEMS"   );
     //
    lua_register(L, "GetItemName", GetItemNameGlue); 
    lua_register(L, "GetItemPrice", GetItemPriceGlue); 
    lua_register(L, "GetSelection", GetSelectionGlue); 

    lua_register(L, "GetMoney", GetMoneyGlue); 
    lua_register(L, "SetMoney", SetMoneyGlue); 




    //所持金決定
 // s_money = (rand()*10000 / RAND_MAX) + 500;
     s_money = 1500;

 //debug.tracebreack関数の実装へのポインタ
 lua_CFunction stack_trace_func = NULL;

 //debug.tracebreackの実装であるＣ関数を取得する
 lua_getglobal(L,"debug");
 if(!lua_isnil(L,-1)){
     lua_getfield(L,-1,"traceback");
    stack_trace_func = lua_tocfunction(L,-1);
    lua_pop(L,1);
 }
     lua_pop(L,1);

 //スタックのサイズを覚えておく

    int top = lua_gettop(L);
 // int ret1 = luaL_dofile(L,"douguya3.lua");   
    int ret1 = luaL_loadfile(L,"douguya3.lua"); 



 //エラー処理関数を積み、その上にグローバル関数shopを積む
     lua_pushcfunction(L,stack_trace_func);
     lua_getglobal(L,"Shop");
     ret1 = lua_pcall(L,0,0,-2);
    if(ret1!=0){
        //実行時エラー
         printf("error: %s\n", lua_tostring(L,-1));
         //スタックを戻す
        lua_settop(L,top);
        printf("<エンターキーを押すとスクリプトを読み直します。>\n");
        getchar();
        //douguya.luaをロードし直す    
        load_script(L);
 //     ret1=load_script(name='douguya3.lua',path='./');
     }
    else{
        //スタックを戻す
         lua_settop(L,top);
         break;
     }

    if(s_money<0){
        s_money=s_money*-1;
    }

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;

 }
```

エラー:test2_1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test2_1.cpp:247:16: error: ‘load_script’ was not declared in this scope
   load_script(L);
                ^
test2_1.cpp:253:3: error: break statement not within loop or switch
   break;
   ^

Comment: このプログラムはCではなくC++なのですか？

Comment: 1つ目のエラーは `load_script()` が定義されていなくて見つからない、と言っており、また lua.h のAPIにはこの関数は定義されていないように見えます。定義したつもりの関数や別のライブラリの関数を呼び出そうとした、などが考えられますが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: レスが遅くなってすみません。nekketsuuuさんCにLuaを組み込んでいます。

Comment: nekettsuuさんload_scriptが関数として定義されていない。アドバイスありがとうございます。教本どおりに打ち込んでいたのですが、教本のダウンロードサイトにはload_scriptならぬLOAD_SCRIPT関数が組み込まれており、こちらを組み込むことで上手くいきました。

Answer (score 3):

アドバイスありがとうございます。教本どおりに打‌​ち込んでいたのですが、教本のダウンロード‌​サイトにはload_scriptならぬL‌​OAD_SCRIPT関数が組み込まれてお‌​り、こちらを組み込むことで上手くいきまし‌​た。

Answer (score 0):

当該のコードの、引数(L)が「lua_State *」型なので、

load_script(L)は
lua_load_script(L)

である可能性が高いと予測できるのですが、いかがでしょう。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。教本どおりに打‌​ち込んでいたのですが、教本のダウンロード‌​サイトにはload_scriptならぬL‌​OAD_SCRIPT関数が組み込まれてお‌​り、こちらを組み込むことで上手くいきまし‌​た。